# Not getting intended output on querying on a list in ElasticSearch

Tags: apache, elasticsearch, lucene, elasticsearch-plugin

======== Tried below to query on a list, but didn’t work=============
Input record:

> ```
> {
>   "somerecord": [
>     {
>       "fieldValue": "1",
>       "sampleKey": [
>         "1",
>         "2"
>       ]
>     },
>     {
>       "fieldValue": "2",
>       "sampleKey": [
>         "3",
>         "4"
>       ]
>     }
>   ]
> }
> ```

Output expected or needed for “fieldValue”:”1” search:

> ```
> {
>   "fieldValue": "1",
>   "sampleKey": [
>     "1",
>     "2"
>   ]
> }
> ```

Steps:
Created a mapping
Put a record
Query using different query types

References:

> http://www.spacevatican.org/2012/6/3/fun-with-elasticsearch-s-children-and-nested-documents/
>   https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/nested-mapping.html
>   https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html
>   https://gist.github.com/nicolashery/6317643
>   http://elasticsearch-cheatsheet.jolicode.com/
>   http://obtao.com/blog/2014/04/elasticsearch-advanced-search-and-nested-objects/
>   http://joelabrahamsson.com/elasticsearch-nested-mapping-and-filter/

Please let me know how to achieve what I intent to.

======== Some of command runs =========
1.

> ```
> curl -XPOST https://someClusterURL/tax2 -d '{
>   "mappings": {
>     "ids": {
>       "properties": {
>         "somerecord": {
>           "type": "nested",
>           "properties": {
>             "fieldValue": {
>               "type": "string"
>             }
>           }
>         }
>       }
>     }
>   }
> }'
> ```

2. > ```
   > curl -XPUT https://someClusterURL/tax2/ids/1 -d '{
   >   "somerecord": [
   >     {
   >       "fieldValue": "1",
   >       "sampleKey": [
   >         "1",
   >         "2"
   >       ]
   >     },
   >     {
   >       "fieldValue": "2",
   >       "sampleKey": [
   >         "3",
   >         "4"
   >       ]
   >     }
   >   ]
   > }'
   > ```
  3.

> ```
> curl -XGET  https://someClusterURL/tax2/ids/_search -d '{
>   "query": {
>     "nested": {
>       "path": "somerecord",
>       "query": {
>         "bool": {
>           "must": [
>             { "match": { "fieldValue": "1" }}
>           ]
>         }
>       }
>     }
>   }
> }'
> ```

Result:

> ```
> {
>   "somerecord": [
>     {
>       "fieldValue": "1",
>       "sampleKey": [
>         "1",
>         "2"
>       ]
>     },
>     {
>       "fieldValue": "2",
>       "sampleKey": [
>         "3",
>         "4"
>       ]
>     }
>   ]
> }
> ```

Tried more, but still didn’t work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Inner_Hits](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-inner-hits.html) and [Source Filtering](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-source-filtering.html) (to disable source) like:

```
{
"_source": false,
"query": {
"nested": {
  "path": "somerecord",
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        { "match": { "fieldValue": "1" }}
       ]
    }
   },
   "inner_hits" :{}
   }
 }
```

Using  `"_source": false` will not fetch the source details.

Comment: Thanks Richa. I tried with it, got the sub-element I am looking for in inner_hits. But my problem hasn't ended here, I don't want complete record. I checked options of inner_hits and other, couldn't see setting for disabling complete record in response. Let me know if its possible.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you store both objects within one nested document. When you have a hit within one nested object the **complete** document is returned.

Do you need nested documents at all?

Comment: Input record is something contains a list & will be stored in ElasticSearch. After matching inner object should be given.

Comment: Then have a look at the [inner hits aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-inner-hits.html). This will give you the inner object, which caused the hit.

Comment: Thanks Michael. I tried with it, got the sub-element I am looking for in inner_hits. But as commented below on Richa's answer, my problem hasn't ended here, I don't want complete record. I checked options of inner_hits and other, couldn't see setting for disabling complete record in response. Let me know if its possible.

Comment: Below [the json examples](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-inner-hits.html#nested-inner-hits) it is explained how to do it. Moreover, Richa has the solution in the answer. ;)

Comment: Yeah! With source filtering it worked. Thanks to Richa & You.